# In Haskell, in Windows 7, can I read a file that is already write-locked by another program?

Tags: windows, file-locking

I have a 3rd party program that is running continuously, and is logging events in a text file. I want to write a small Haskell program that reads the text file while the other program is running and warns me when certain events are logged.

I looked around and it seems as if, for Windows, readFile is single write OR multiple read - it does not allow single write and multiple read. As I understand it, this is to avoid side effects like the write changing the file after/during reads.

Is there some way for me to work around this constraint on locks? The log file is only appended, and I am only looking for specific rows in the file, so I really don't mind if I don't get the most recent write, as I am interested in eventual consistency and will keep checking the file.

Comment: I think your problem is not Haskell, but Windows. The "single write or multiple read" mode you read about is only enforced by the Haskell runtime inside of the same Haskell program (between multiple threads). In C, you would use a flag like `_SH_DENYNO` when opening the file for writing, but since you don't control the writing end, this might be a tough problem to solve.

Comment: If only you could bait and switch the target file for a named pipe. But alas, in Windows, named pipes live in `\\.\pipe\PipeName` territory.

Comment: After playing around some more I found that while it's ugly, using system to copy the log file to a temp file every few seconds and then working from the temp file seems to work for me.

Comment: @user2253023 since you found a solution could you post it as an answer and accept it to remove this question from the unanswered queue?